# Using map with a function

Tags: list, function, haskell, dictionary

I have 2 Functions

```
accelerate :: Float -> [Particle] -> [Particle]
accelerateParticle :: Float -> Particle -> [Particle] -> Particle
```

and what I am trying to achieve is for every element in `[Particle]` apply the `accelerateParticle` function. The trouble I have run into is that the `accelerateParticle` function relies on using the original `[particle]` that is given initally by accelerate. I was thinking of using map like this

`map (\particle -> accelerateParticle Float particle [Particle]) [Particle]`

but I'm not very sure if this the correct format.

Comment: The question is not clear to me: 1. You say you have two functions `accelerate` and `accelerateParticle`. Do you already have implementations of both these functions with you, or do you want to implement these functions? 2. You say you want to apply the `accelerateParticle` function to every element in `[Particle]`. *Where* do you want to do this? Are you trying to implement a third function, or are you trying to implement one of these two functions using the other? 3. What is"the original `[particle]` that is given initally by `accelerate`"? Is this the list which  `accelerate` returns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be looking for this:

```
accelerate :: Float -> [Particle] -> [Particle]
accelerate x ps = map (\p -> accelerateParticle x p ps) ps
```

Note that the list of all particles `ps` is used both to `map` over it, and as a parameter of `accelerateParticle`.